# KeyError at /admin/login/ 'token'

Tags: python, django, heroku

After deploying my Django Application to Heroku I have found the following error:

KeyError at /admin/login/ 'token' with the following trace:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: https://decide-picaro-authentication.herokuapp.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/

Django Version: 2.0
Python Version: 3.8.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'corsheaders',
 'django_filters',
 'rest_framework',
 'rest_framework.authtoken',
 'rest_framework_swagger',
 'gateway',
 'authentication',
 'base',
 'booth',
 'census',
 'mixnet',
 'postproc',
 'store',
 'visualizer',
 'voting',
 'social_django']
Installed Middleware:
('whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'social_django.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware')



Traceback:

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  44.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in login
  398.         return LoginView.as_view(**defaults)(request)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  62.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/debug.py" in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
  76.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  58.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  62.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  58.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  62.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  44.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  58.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py" in dispatch
  65.         return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  89.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in post
  141.         if form.is_valid():

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in is_valid
  179.         return self.is_bound and not self.errors

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in errors
  174.             self.full_clean()

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in full_clean
  377.         self._clean_form()

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in _clean_form
  404.             cleaned_data = self.clean()

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py" in clean
  195.             self.user_cache = authenticate(self.request, username=username, password=password)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py" in authenticate
  70.             user = _authenticate_with_backend(backend, backend_path, request, credentials)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py" in _authenticate_with_backend
  115.     return backend.authenticate(*args, **credentials)

File "/app/decide/base/backends.py" in authenticate
  27.             request.session['auth-token'] = token['token']

Exception Type: KeyError at /admin/login/
Exception Value: 'token'
```

I don't know why would this happen, apparently this happened after doing two changes:
-Moving my API keys to the local_settings
-Adding the dependency python-environ on requirements.txt

The login on both admin and my login view worked properly before these two changes, this not happens at all on my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

I was using a different BASE URL on my settings.py, also changed the way the secret key is retrieved.